# How to create ajax pagination to php MVC Controller

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create pagination with ajax and php, but when I click to the pagination link won't work. I tried to set different URL, and changing the method from get to post method but still I have the same problem, Here is the php library that I have used together with my model and controller methods.

// Php Pagination library

```
  <?php

    /*
    ** PHP Pagination Class
    *** https://github.com/dcblogdev/pagination
    */
    class Paginator{
        private $_perPage, $_instance, $_page, $_limit, $_totalRows = 0,  $_customCSS;

        public function __construct($perPage, $instance, $customCSS = ''){
            $this->_instance = $instance;       
            $this->_perPage = $perPage;
            $this->set_instance();
            $this->_customCSS = $customCSS; 
        }

        public function get_start(){ 
            return ($this->_page * $this->_perPage) - $this->_perPage; 
        }

        private function set_instance(){
            $this->_page = (int) (!isset($_GET[$this->_instance]) ? 1 : $_GET[$this->_instance]); 
            $this->_page = ($this->_page == 0 ? 1 : $this->_page < 0 ? 1 : $this->_page);
        }

        public function set_total($_totalRows){ 
            $this->_totalRows = $_totalRows; 
        }

        public function get_limit(){ 
            return "LIMIT ".$this->get_start().",$this->_perPage"; 
        }

        public function get_limit_keys(){ 
            return ['offset' => $this->get_start(), 'limit' => $this->_perPage]; 
        }

        public function page_links($path='?',$ext = null){
            $adjacents = "2";
            $prev = $this->_page - 1;
            $next = $this->_page + 1;
            $lastpage = ceil($this->_totalRows/$this->_perPage);
            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

            $pagination = "";
            if($lastpage > 1)
            {   
                $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination ".$this->_customCSS."'>";
                if ($this->_page > 1){
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='".$path."$this->_instance=$prev"."$ext' id='click-pagination' data-id='".$counter."'>Prev</a></li>";  
                }

                if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){   
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='".$path."$this->_instance=$counter"."$ext' id='click-pagination' data-id='".$counter."'>$counter</a></li>";                   
                }               
            }
            else{

                if ($this->_page < $counter - 1){
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='".$path."$this->_instance=$next"."$ext' id='click-pagination' data-id='".$counter."'>Next</a></li>";
                }
                else{
                    $pagination.= "</ul>\n";       
                }
            }
        return $pagination;
        }
    }
```

// my controller and controller methods

```
        //Controller method

        public function showAllEvents($page = false)
        {
            if (isset($_GET['page'])) { $page = $_GET['page']; }

            $pages = new Paginator('10', $page);                
            $countallevent = $pages->set_total( $this->model->countAllEvents() );
            $allevent = $this->model->showAllEvents( $pages->get_limit() );
            $pagelink = $pages->page_links('/event/?page'); 

            $html ='';
            foreach ($allevent as $r) {
                $html .= '<div>' .ucfirst($r->event_name). '</div>';
            }
            $html .= $pagelink;
            echo json_encode($html);
        }

   //my model methods

    public function showAllEvents($limit){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * events" . $limit );
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function countAllEventss(){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * Events");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
```

// my index.php

```
   <div class="showAllEvents"></div>

    <script>
    (function($){
        showAllEvent();

        $(document).on('click', '#click-pagination', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).data('id');
            showAllEvents(page);
         })
    })(jQuery);

    function showAllEvents(page){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= URL; ?>' + '/Pastor/showAllEvents',
            method: 'post',
            data:{ page : page},
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                $('.showAllEvent').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209999/discussion-on-question-by-one-buyu-how-to-create-ajax-pagination-to-php-mvc-cont).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There few things that you need to change

1/ File index.php

a) Function showAllEvents Ajax
Remove the line `dataType : 'JSON'`, because you're receiving html instead of json
Ajax Request method shoud be GET, because you're reading _GET in controller and in Paging class

2/ Your controller

`$pages = new Paginator('10', 'page');`

instead of

`$pages = new Paginator('10', $page);`

Just `echo $html;` because you need the output in html format

3/ Your model

All query shoud be `" SELECT * FROM events "` (you're missing extra space)

4/ Your paging class

I don't want to edit too much in this file, but if you want to add `data-page`, you just need to insert that tag to all li > a tag: `data-page={the destination page}`

Comment: Thank you Very much @Van Tho. In that way I can't use post method?

Comment: Yeah so you need to change `_GET` to `_POST` in the class pagination

Comment: Ok, Thank you, It working now, you have saved my day. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome :D BTW I suggest that you shoud return JSON data from PHP, then show html by js, instead of link, you can use `span` or `button` and event `onclick`

Comment: Thank you, I will change them as you recommended.